# javascript synchronize code execution between tabs

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser, local-storage

I have a dilemma. I'm using this code to generate an unique ID and store it in a cookie or local storage. I'm only generating this ID if there is no previous ID set.

```
//read the ID from cookie or local storage
var id=readID();
if(id==null){
   //no ID found, generate an ID
   id=generateID();

   //store the ID to use it when we come back
   storeID(id);
}
```

This code works as I expected around 90% of the time, generating only one ID, but sometimes when a user with no ID opens 2 or more tabs in the same time(or on very short intervals) it ends up generating 2 IDs.
What I'm interested is some hack strategy to lock the code when reading,generating and storing the ID, and to be executed only in one tab. until the lock is released.

I know this might not work because tabs are separated, but I was thinking if you could lock on a local storage object for both read and write?

I'm open to other solutions as well.

**UPDATE**: I was asked how generateID algorithm is. I say it doesn't matter, but to simplify this we'll use `Math.random()` like this:

```
function generateID(){
   return Math.random();
}
```

Comment: How long does it take to generate an ID?

Comment: Read http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/

Comment: I guess I'd need to see what readID() and generateID are doing, but localstorage at least should communicate between tabs. Take a look at the Web Storage API for reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: I don't think it matter how generateID algorithm is, but to keep it simple let's say I use Math.random(). The problem still persists. I've also updated the main post

Comment: Than before you set the id, see if one exists.

Comment: @epascarello if you look at the code, that's what I'm checking. but sometimes 2 times detect that no ID is generated, and generate 2 different IDs.

Comment: I am suggesting that you check it after you generate it to see if it was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your readID function is quick. Try this:

```
const now = new Date().getTime() // Number -> 1471016775000 (ms since epoch)
const id = readID()
if (!id) {
    storeID(now)
    id = generateID()
    const lookup = readID()
    if (lookup === now) {
        // this confirms this is the window that started generating the ID
        storeID(id)
    }

}
```

Comment: haha... good hack, the only problem will be if 2 tabs have the same now value

Comment: Oops. Drop the / 1000 from first line for milliseconds. The chances this code is going to get executed in multiple tabs with the same MILLISECOND since epoch is pretty... unlikely. Good value as any to use to lock.

Comment: Yes. I've found a more complex library and it seems that is similar to your example. They use date + random number just to be sure. `now() + ":" + someNumber();` : https://bitbucket.org/balpha/lockablestorage/src/96b7ddb1962334cde9c647663d0053ab640ec5a1/lockablestorage.js?fileviewer=file-view-default

Comment: you can read more about this at : http://balpha.de/2012/03/javascript-concurrency-and-locking-the-html5-localstorage/